# Using Powershell v2.0 nd XPATH to read xml component containing multiple attributes

Tags: xml, xpath, powershell-2.0

I cannot find a suitable answer to this as all the examples relate to a regular or standard form of `XML` structure. I am trying to search a directory of xml files, and I want to limit to those that have a particular "OrderDate" attribute specified in the xml. So the PS script is to filter to a particular value, but I am unable to get PS to reference this attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Order Value="28.78" Lines="3" OrderDate="2016-03-21" SupplierName="ASupplier" OrderNo="1234">
<Line UnitCost="5.28" PackSize="Box 44" Quantity="1" ImpExpRef="1234" LineNo="1"/>
<Line UnitCost="18" PackSize="Box180" Quantity="1" ImpExpRef="1234" LineNo="2"/>
<Line UnitCost="5.5" PackSize="5Ltr" Quantity="1" ImpExpRef="1234" LineNo="3"/>
</Order>
```

As you can see, there are two nodes (or elements?): Order and Line, and there  multiple attributes for each and don't have their own node, so I can't work out how to `XPATH` this file.

The current script just to isolate the attribute is:

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-content "C:\example.xml"
$XPath = '//Order[@OrderDate]'    
$nodes = Select-Xml $XmlDocument -XPATH $xpath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
```

and the results are:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $nodes

OrderNo      : 1234
SupplierName : ASupplier
OrderDate    : 2016-03-21
Lines        : 3
Value        : 28.78
Line         : {Line, Line, Line}
```

It doesn't recognise `@OrderDate` as an attribute, or any other attribute for that matter, presumably because there are multiple attributes under "Order", it's as if it's ignoring it. Same result if `$XPath = '//Order[@*]'`

All examples I have researched assume one attribute per node (or element)

Comment: It isn't clear what do you want the XPath to return? `Order` element or `OrderDate` attribute or something else?

Comment: You can use XPath to filter by `OrderDate` attribute value, if that's what you want : `//Order[@OrderDate='2016-03-21']`

Comment: Sorry, I want to search xmls based on their OrderDate (specific date). I tried what you suggested but it doesn't return any values as if it ignores it. If, however, I remove all attributes in Order but one, say Value, then it works, as this is the only attribute in this element. It's only when there are multiple attributes under one element and I cannot work out how to limit to any one attribute.

Comment: So if the xml now only has the Value attribute, removing Lines, OrderDate, SupplierName and OrderNo, then the XPATH statement filters out as expected. Normally I would see each attribute enclosed with it's own element

Comment: is the problem specific to powershell v2? Do you have newer version powershell to test? Because it seems to work fine in my powershell v4 ...

Answer (score 0):

> *"I tried what you suggested but it doesn't return any values as if it ignores it"*

I maybe missing something about how you tried it or what you are trying to achieve actually (please clarify). The following is what I did *exactly*, and it returned the expected element :

```
PS C:\Users\Foo> $XmlDocument = [xml]@"
>> <Order Value="28.78" Lines="3" OrderDate="2016-03-21" SupplierName="ASupplier" OrderNo="1234">
>> <Line UnitCost="5.28" PackSize="Box 44" Quantity="1" ImpExpRef="1234" LineNo="1"/>
>> <Line UnitCost="18" PackSize="Box180" Quantity="1" ImpExpRef="1234" LineNo="2"/>
>> <Line UnitCost="5.5" PackSize="5Ltr" Quantity="1" ImpExpRef="1234" LineNo="3"/>
>> </Order>
>> "@
>>
PS C:\Users\Foo> $XPath = "//Order[@OrderDate='2016-03-21']"
PS C:\Users\Foo> $nodes = Select-Xml $XmlDocument -XPATH $xpath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
PS C:\Users\Foo> $nodes


Value        : 28.78
Lines        : 3
OrderDate    : 2016-03-21
SupplierName : ASupplier
OrderNo      : 1234
Line         : {Line, Line, Line}
```

**UPDATE :**

In response to your comment below, the XPath `//Order[@OrderDate='2016-03-21']` returns *`Order` element* that have certain `OrderDate` attribute value. By *`Order` element* I mean the entire element leaving none of its part. You can't return `Order` element that contains only one attribute i.e `OrderDate` attribute, because there is no such element in the original XML. You can, however, returns just the target attribute using the following XPath :

```
//Order/@OrderDate[.='2016-03-21']
```

Comment: Where you have listed six attributes in your results, I am trying to only output the attribute value for "OrderDate     :  2016-03-21", I am not interested in Value, Lines, SupplierName, OrderNo and Line. So I am expect the variable $nodes to only contain this, but it returns all attributes

Comment: I have worked this out with the help of an XML reader - the correct syntax is